# Is Steam Safe? It has its own repositories

Tags: steam

I installed Steam, but saw it uses its own repositories for upgrading, and I don't know if it is safe to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

The repo Steam adds is officially maintained by Valve, so it should all be safe. Many people use Steam on Ubuntu daily.